# vba access show duplicate data with min date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there any way to find the min(Creation Date) and delete it from the access query ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRs9Y.png)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp    and   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: this is a SQL question, not VBA. please correct your tags

Comment: What have you tried. Explain more about what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to remove a result from a query? or are you trying to remove that record entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use MIN() function to select the records with MIN() date.

```
SELECT Item_Number, Order_Number, Order_Line_Number,  MIN(Creation_Date) 
FROM *tblName*
GROUP BY Item_Number, Order_Number, Order_Line_Number
```

or you can use MAX() function on 'Creation Date' column to exclude records with the minimum date.

```
SELECT Item_Number, Order_Number, Order_Line_Number,  MAX(Creation_Date) 
FROM *tblName*
GROUP BY Item_Number, Order_Number, Order_Line_Number
```

or if you as originally mentioned really wanted to delete the records from MS Access table with MIN() date then use the below query.

```
DELETE **tbl_A.*** FROM 
*tblName tbl_A* INNER JOIN *tblName tbl_B* 
WHERE 
tbl_A.Item_Number = tbl_B.Item_Number
AND
tbl_A.Order_Number = tbl_B.Order_Number
AND
tbl_A.Order_Line_Number = tbl_B.Order_Line_Number
AND
tbl_A.Creation_Date = tbl_B.MIN(Creation_Date)
```